# Chinese language support in Windows, installed language packs but some apps still show gibberish text

Tags: windows, character-encoding, chinese, language-pack

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate and I've installed both the Traditional and Simplified Chinese language packs. A lot of software works with Chinese text now and I'm also able to use Chinese input.

Some applications however, still don't seem to work:

[image: Application with gibberish text]

Does anybody know what I'm missing here?

(The appplication in the screenshot is just one example, there are many)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, some applications (especially older ones that pre-date the language support found today) simply are hard-coded as to where they pull their "encoding" from. Regardless of what language pack you install, they do not use it, and continue to use the encoding of the OS.